Does it possible to implement In-App update in kotlin MainActivity from Flutter App?
My flutter app is main core is kotlin.
I see some dependency in pub dev but is not I prefer.
I see on android docs In-App Update provide way to implement for In-App update, due my flutter app(base kotlin) so can I implement that function on mainActivity in kotlin?
I possible to do please kindly how to that.
Thank you!

yes. it is possible. You can write code in MainActivity which extends FlutterActivity.
